# "npm install -g newman" command is not working for installing newman in windows

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, newman

Installation fails using

- `node -v`  v10.16.0
- `npm -v` 6.9.0

This is the output

> The operation was rejected by your operating system. It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus), or that you lack permissions to access it.
>
> If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

```bash
C:\Users\Atanu>npm install -g newman
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\Vbrick\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, 
         mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Vbrick\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, 
         mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Vbrick\nodejs\node_modules\.staging']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, 
   mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Vbrick\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Vbrick\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, 
      mkdir \'C:\\Program Files\\Vbrick\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Vbrick\\nodejs\\node_modules\\.staging',
npm ERR!   parent: 'newman' }
... 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     
C:\Users\Atanu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-20T06_37_27_595Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try running as admin, looks like permission error: ```The operation was rejected by your operating system```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the command prompt as admin.